# How do you would convert this Query to Method Syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, methods, syntax

I'm curious to now how can I convert this query syntax:

```
Esperienze = (from e in Esperienze
             from p in e.PeriodiValidita.Cast<PeriodoValidita>()
             where UiUtils.IntersectDatesRanges(DateTime.Parse(p.ValidoDal), DateTime.Parse(p.ValidoAl), DataInizioDT, DataFineDT)
             select e).Distinct();
```

to method syntax in LINQ. `.SelectMany`?

Comment: Should be fairly easy to map using Intellisense, no?

Comment: I don't know how to merge the two initial from/from

Comment: combination of SelectMany + Distinct is the right way to go

Comment: @Andrew: can you show us an example?

Comment: sorry, it looks like you are selecting Esperienze items.. than the query should be like this `context.Esperienze.Where(e=> e.PeriodiValidita.Any(p=> UiUtils.IntersectDatesRanges(DateTime.Parse(p.ValidoDal), DateTime.Parse(p.ValidoAl), DataInizioDT, DataFineDT))).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: @Andrew If you're using `Any` rather than `SelectMany`, do you still need the `Distinct`? And why the `ToList`?

Comment: as I understand you want to select Esperienze where at least one PeriodiValidita intersect with your data ranges. that's why I select esperienzes where at least one(any) periodvalidita satisfies the condition. if there are no duplicates in Esperienze table, you don't need Distinct, but you need to call the ToList method to enumerate the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://lq2m.azurewebsites.net/) I get

```
Esperienze
    .SelectMany(e => e.PeriodiValidita.Cast<PeriodoValidita>(), (e, p) => new { e, p })
    .Where(τ0 => UiUtils.IntersectDatesRanges(
        DateTime.Parse(τ0.p.ValidoDal),
        DateTime.Parse(τ0.p.ValidoAl),
        DataInizioDT,
        DataFineDT))
    .Select(τ0 => τ0.e)
    .Distinct()
```

for the query plus the `Distinct`.

In the spec you're looking for this part of section **7.16.2.4 7.16.2.4** *From, let, where, join and orderby clauses*:

> A query expression with a second from clause followed by something other than a select clause:

```
from x1 in e1
from x2 in e2
…
```

> is translated into

```
from * in ( e1 ) . SelectMany( x1 => e2 , ( x1 , x2 ) => new { x1 , x2 } )
…
```